# How to return to the previous page in Selenium IDE

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-ide

It is possible to return to the previous page using the selenium IDE editor, I have already tried 2 options

Sending the key combination to go back a page in Google Chrome

[image]

and the other use the Chrome console to force it to return to the previous page

[image]

but none of them work for me.

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Try with this to go back in browser:
execute script | history.back()

You can also use this to go to forward:
execute script | history.forward()

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `run script` command is changed at `execute script`
Use it with `window.history.go(-1)` and it will work